# Clarification for binary search in solving optimal TSP when a polynomial algorithm with a budge exists

Tags: np-hard, np, traveling-salesman, binary-search

Below is Question 8.1 in *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al.

[image: Question 8.1]

There's a solution to this problem that uses binary search from [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp08/cse101/hw/hw6soln.pdf). Pasting the answer for posterity.

[image: Solution]

My questions are:

1. When they say input size, are they just referring to edges or both
   edges and vertices?
2. Is it correct to say that we make at most $log( |E| log K)$ calls?
3. Does this work if the edge weights aren't integers, like `10.4` etc?
4. Why is this **NP-Hard** as the solution mentions? I thought that Traveling Salesperson Problem was **NP-Complete**

This [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384800/finding-the-optimum-cost-of-a-traveling-salesman-solution) asks for clarification of binary search use but doesn't answer the above question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Input size refers to memory size needed to represent the input. In this case, it means number of edges + number of vertices, and you could also add size of the weights (which is logarithmic in their values).
2. No. It is written that we do $\log T$ calls and $T \leq |E| K$ (and this value can be reached), so the number of calls is at most $\log (|E| K) = \log |E| + \log K$.
3. Yes. It is never used in the algorithm that weights must be integers.
4. A $NP$-complete problem is a $NP$-hard problem which also needs to be in $NP$. So when speaking about a $NP$-complete problem, it is not false to state that it is $NP$-hard. However, $NP$ is a set of decision problems, therefore, TSP-OPT being an optimization problem cannot be in $NP$. We can still speak about $NP$-hardness as it can be informally defined for a non-decision problem as "a problem more difficult than all problems in $NP$". When you say "I thought that Traveling Salesperson Problem was NP-Complete", it refers to the decision version, denoted TSP in your reference.